# Извините, нет записей, удовлетворяющих вашим условиям

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

Пытаюсь реализовать вывод дополнительных статей по клику.
Делаю через `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 6;
    $('#click').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "post_load.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {"num": num}
        }).done(function(data){

            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.length > 0){
                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    $("#news").append("<div class='galon'><div class='imag'><figure class='effect-honey'>"+the_post_thumbnail+"<figcaption></figcaption></figure></div><h3>"+data.pos_title+"</h3><p>"+data.post_content+"</p></div>");
                });
                num += 6;
            }

        });
    });
});
```

`GET` отправляет в соответствующий файл:

```
require_once("db_connect.php"); 


$num = $_GET['num'];


$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' ORDER BY 'id' LIMIT {$num}, 6");

$news = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $news[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($news);
```

Но в консоли выдает `404` ошибку в файле `jquery.min.js` (подключал из гугла), а на сайте "Извините, нет записей, удовлетворяющих вашим условиям.". Но статьи точно есть, так как через `WP` выводятся 6 статей, всего их 12. Не могу понять в чем дело и что не так делаю, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Запрос вообще уходит?

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 GET http://mysite.org/post_load.php?num=6 404 (Not Found)

Вот что пишет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передавать GET параметры в `url`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 6;
    $('#click').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "post_load.php?num=" + num,
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function(data){

            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.length > 0){
                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    $("#news").append("<div class='galon'><div class='imag'><figure class='effect-honey'>"+the_post_thumbnail+"<figcaption></figcaption></figure></div><h3>"+data.pos_title+"</h3><p>"+data.post_content+"</p></div>");
                });
                num += 6;
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ваш способ сдвинул дело с мертвой точки, но теперь дебагер выдает "anonimus function" в предпоследних закрывающих скобках

Comment: @Dzmitri Я так думаю он говорит что там произошла ошибка.проверь чтоб data был валидным json строкой.Да и запятые убери после method: "GET". Я поправил ответ.Но а так вроде все нормально

Comment: запятую убрал. вот что в консоли выдает:

jquery.min.js:4 GET http://goodfood.is-great.org/post_load.php?num=6 404 (Not Found)send 
@ jquery.min.js:4r.extend.ajax 
@ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
@ (index):72r.event.dispatch 
@ jquery.min.js:3q.handle 
@ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Это означает что путь к PHP файлу не правилен.Проверь что твой сайт открывается по goodfood.is-great.org/post_load.php?num=6.Надо вам правильный путь прописать на котором ваш код работает

Comment: открывается сайт, но вместо статей "Извините, нет записей, удовлетворяющих вашим условиям."

Comment: @Dzmitri Я проверил. По этому адресу ваш сайт не доступен.То Есть ваша система устроена так что любая несуществующая ссылка ведет на нее http://goodfood.is-great.org/post_load.php/aaa/vvv/ccc. Она возвращает заголовок 404 NotFound.Разберись с сайтом.

Comment: так, а как сделать что бы она существовала? проблема в запросе к бд?

Comment: Нет в ссылке.Что это за движок  ? Посмотри как там routing работает

Comment: на wordpress делаю

Comment: Нука пошли мне любую ссылку на котором продукт есть

Comment: нет продукта, да и не планируется. просто статьи

Comment: И кстати method: "GET" замены на  method: "POST".Может получиться

Comment: Ну тогда ссылку с одной статьей существующей

Comment: POST не прокатил, то же самое выдает. статьи просматриваются сразу на главной, то есть кнопки "читать далее" или что то в этом духе, не будет. то есть открыл сайт, и сразу новости в блоках.

Comment: Нyко свяжись со мной по скайпу vanya.avchyan

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 6;
    $('#click').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "post_load.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: "num=" + num,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){

            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.length > 0){
                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    $("#news").append("<div class='galon'><div class='imag'><figure class='effect-honey'>"+the_post_thumbnail+"<figcaption></figcaption></figure></div><h3>"+data.pos_title+"</h3><p>"+data.post_content+"</p></div>");
                });
                num += 6;
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Так попробуйте в вашем случае `$_GET['num'];` не будет.
И проверьте еще запрос `$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' ORDER BY 'id' LIMIT 6, 6");`, у вас, по идее, получится.

Comment: и еще советую {$num} к инту привести перед тем как в запрос вставлять.... )

Comment: к сожалению ошибка не исправлена!(

Comment: запрос поправили?